# Match words separated by semicolon and ending with 'ase anydigit'

Tags: regex, perl

Can anybody help me to get the words having `ase` at the end of words using regular expressions.

My text is like this:

> Vasopressin V1a receptor; Vasopressin V1b receptor; Vasopressin V2
>   receptor; Prostaglandin G/H synthase 1; Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2

Now I want only `Prostaglandin G/H synthase 1; Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2` which are ending with `ase` .

I want the query to be generic as i will be running this for 7000 records using. It should separate the words with before ase at the end as mentioned in the example

Comment: *Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2* is ending with a number, not "ase". Also,show us what you've tried

Comment: correct that it is not ending with "ase".. thats what  i want words before and after ase. I tried :

Comment: I tried enough including:   .*\w.\w.;*\.*.\w*(ase)\w*.*   But it is giving me earlier words also

Comment: Is the `Prostaglandin G/H synthase 1` really broken over two lines in your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perlish solution:

1. Split the words on ; separator
2. Apply regex to each word and print if it matches the criteria

Sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = split/;/, <DATA>;
foreach my $word (@words){
    if ($word =~ /ase \d+$/){
        print $word;    
    }
}

__DATA__
Vasopressin V1a receptor; Vasopressin V1b receptor; Vasopressin V2 receptor; Prostaglandin G/H synthase 1; Prostaglandin G/H synthase 2
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/zIrZ8c)

Comment: @ Chankey Pathak: Thank you very much for the solution. This is also a great solution. Also thank you everyone for giving ur valuable time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?<=;\s)[^;]+ase\s\d+` which finds and captures everything after a semicolon until "ase[space][number]"

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/JK65Rq/4)

Comment: May I suggest `(?<=; )` instead of a literal semicolon? That way you can keep everything you match

Comment: And remove the group brackets: `(?<=;\s)[^;]+ase\s\d+` . The *whole* match is the target - no need for groups